# Suspense returns data too fast in @tanstack/react-query v4

Tags: react-query

I am upgrading a React app from react-query v3 to @tanstack/react-query v4.

Almost everything works, but I'm having a problem with Suspense.

I have a react component:

```
const WrapperPageEdit: React.FC<MyProps> = ({
  pageUuid,
  redirect,
}: MyProps) => {
  const FormPage = React.lazy(() => import('./FormPage'));
  const { data } = usePageView(pageUuid);

  if (data?.[0]) {
    const pageObjectToEdit= data[0];
    const content = pageObjectToEdit.myStuff.content;

    return (
      <Suspense
        fallback={<Trans id="loading.editor">Loading the editor...</Trans>}
      >
        <FormPage
          id={uuid}
          content={content}
          redirect={redirect}
        />
      </Suspense>
    );
  }
  return <p>No data.</p>;
};
```

And here's my query:

```
export function usePageView(
  uuid: string,
): UseQueryResult<DrupalPage[], Error> {
  return useQuery<DrupalPage[], Error>(
    queryKeyUsePageView(uuid),
    async () => {
      return fetchAnon(getPageByPageUuid(uuid));
    },
    {
      cacheTime: YEAR_MILLISECONDS,
      staleTime: YEAR_MILLISECONDS,
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        if (data?.[0]) {
          data.map((element) => processResult(element));
        }
      },
    },
  );
}
```

This works in v3 but fails in v4 with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content')

The reason the property is undefined is because that property is set by the processing in `onSuccess` (`data.map`).

The issue appears to be that in v4, the component `WrapperPageEdit` is refreshed before `onSuccess` in the `usePageView` query has finished processing, whereas in v3, the component `WrapperPageEdit` is not refreshed until the `onSuccess` `data.map` is complete.

How can I correctly fix this?  I can write some additional code to try to check whether the `onSuccess` `data.map` is complete, but since react-query handled this automatically in v3, I'd like to rewrite my code in v4 so that it is the same.

Comment: not sure I understand the code - what is data.map(processResult) doing? is it mutating the result? that's something you shouldn't be doing in v3 either. why not do it directly in the queryFn ?

Comment: Yes, it is mutating the result (based on the returned data, calculating some new properties and adding them to `data`).  I never did it in the queryFn because... I didn't think of doing it that way.  That makes way more sense.  Feel free to post an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are mutating the data in `onSuccess`. Directly modifying data in callbacks is not a good idea. Instead, do your transformation for example directly in the queryFn:

```
async () => {
  const data = fetchAnon(getPageByPageUuid(uuid));
  if (data?.[0]) {
    data.map((element) => processResult(element));
  }
  return data
},
```

other good places to do data transformation is e.g. the `select` option, but it should always happen in an immutable way, because otherwise, you are overwriting the cached data inadvertently. React prefers updates to be immutable.